# Excel file is exported without data using react-export-excel

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react-export-excel to generate an excel file

```
 <ExcelFile filename = "Inventory">
      <ExcelSheet data = {excel} name="lecturas" element={ <button className="bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-600 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded mt-1" onClick={handleClick}> Download</button>}>
      <ExcelColumn label="Code" value="code"/>
      <ExcelColumn label="Description" value="description"/>
      </ExcelSheet>
</ExcelFile>
```

I bring the data from a REST API service by pressing the button contained within the element property of ExcelSheet

```
const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(textInput);
  
    const data = {
      uuid:textInput
    };
   axios
      .post("http://localhost:3500/api/data", data)
      .then(res => setExcel(res.data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
      console.log("data")
      console.log(excel)
      
  }
```

The error that it generates is that the first time I press the button it tells me that the data is undefined, but if I press the button again it generates the excel with the data without problem. I think it is because it still does not bring the data when the excel is being generated. I'm trying to get it to wait for data to not be undefined in order to generate the file.

Comment: Yes because `axios.post()` happens, and immediately the data is exported, but it's still empty. Then, the `.then()` (hence the name) part executes, and data gets defined, but too late, the export already occurred. That's how asynchronous functions work. You need to have your data ready first, and _then_ click the export button.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to use npm install xlsx file-saver to generate de excel file.